# 'first-class array': not supported

Tags: arrays, webgl

For the following code:

```
vec4[8] Get8Neighbours(sampler2D sampler)
{
    int i = 0;
    vec2 at;
    vec4[8] ret;
    vec2 step = vec2(1.0) / uResolution.x;
    for(float x = -1.0; x < 2.0; x++)
    {
        for(float y = -1.0; y < 2.0; y++)
        {
            if(x != 0.0 || y != 0.0)
            {
                at = vec2(x,y);
                ret[i] = texture2D(sampler, vTextureCoord + (at * step));
                i++;
            }
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
```

I'm getting the error from the title. What part of this is not supported in WebGL? The error message does not really help much, and Google does not give me any hits. Can't I use arrays in WebGL?

Answer (score 2):

You of course can use Arrays in GLSL but the support is limited. Everything you can and can't do with arrays is documented in the [OpenGL ES Shading Language 1.0 spec](https://www.khronos.org/files/opengles_shading_language.pdf). I'm taking the liberty of simply copy & pasting the relevant paragraph for your problem out of it - But there are a lot more gotchas surrounding arrays so you may want to read the spec anyway.

from § **6.1 Function Definitions**

> Arrays are allowed as arguments, but not as the return type. When arrays are declared as formal
>   parameters, their size must be included. An array is passed to a function by using the array name without
>   any subscripting or brackets, and the size of the array argument passed in must match the size specified in
>   the formal parameter declaration.